# Gradle sync-Error:No service of type StyledTextOutputFactory available in ProjectScopeServices

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, gradle, spring-boot

This is a newly created empty project.
This is my build.gradle file.The error in question happens on apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

```
group 'com.teamtreehouse'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.3.RELEASE')
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a breaking API change in Gradle 3.0 that means that 1.3.3.RELEASE of Spring Boot's Gradle plugin isn't compatible with it. You either need to downgrade Gradle to 2.x or upgrade Spring Boot to 1.5.x.